# Monotouch iPhone Dev error when trying to make any action on an Interface Builder Defined Object using the iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, events, xamarin.ios

I get The following error on runtime

2011-06-08 14:11:04.712 app[8329:207] -[__NSCFSet BridgeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x875c350

Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFSet BridgeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x875c350
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31 
  at app.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/ab/Projects/app/app/Main.cs:19

The error occurs when I am trying to make an action on a button defined at Interface Builder.

I use MonoDevelop 2.4.2, Mono 2.10.1, and iPhone Simulator 4.1.. The error happens only by using the simulator..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to post some code for us to get any further with this. It looks similar to problems I have had where objects have been GC'd underneath me - leaving the iOS objects intact, but blowing up with this sort of error when a button is clicked, for example.

Comment: vlad259, that's it unfortunately.. I went back to monotouch 3.2.6 and all is ok now.. I suppose that there is a workaround, or the intension to fix it by the MonoProject guys..

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to the view around?

Comment: yes I am.. The view is defined at class level. The thing is that if i try to access controls defined at Interface Builder, the app is crushing ("randomly" on device, constantly on simulator). If I access controls defined in code I have no problems (yet). AnyWays that bug must be fixed somehow.